# Could someone check my attempt at a proof of a theorem in the lambda calculus?

Tags: solution-verification, lambda-calculus

I am working through Barendregt's "The Lambda Calculus" and attempted a proof of a proposition in chapter 2 § 1.

Definitions -

$$
\begin{align}
\\
\text{A $context$ C[ ]}&\text{is a term with some holes in it. More formally,}
\\
&\text{$x$ is a context}
\\
&\text{[ ] is a context}
\\
&\text{if $C_1$[ ] and $C_2$[ ] are contexts, then so are $C_1$[ ]$C_2$[ ] and $(\lambda  x.C_1$[ ]$)$}
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
&\text{If $C$[ ] is a context and $M \in \Lambda$, then $C$[$M$] denotes the result of placing $M$ in the holes of $C$[ ].}
\\
&\text{In this act free variables of $M$ may become bound in $C$[$M$]}
\end{align}
$$

$$
\text{EXAMPLE: $C$[ ] $\equiv$ $\lambda x.x(\lambda y.$[ ]$)$ is a context. If $M \equiv xy$, then $C$[$M$]$\equiv\lambda x.x(\lambda y.xy)$}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
&\text{Contexts are not considered modulo $\alpha$-congruence.}
\\
&\text{The essential feature of a context $C$[ ] is that a free variable in $M$ may become bound in $C[$M$].$}
\\
&\text{$Par$ $abus$ $de$ $langage$ we write $C$[ ] $\in \Lambda$ to indicate that $C$[ ] is a context}
\end{align}
$$

Proposition: $\forall C[\space\space\space]\space\forall \space \vec{x} \space \exists F \space \forall M \in \Lambda^0(\vec{x})\space\space\space C[M] = F(\lambda \vec{x}.M)$

Proof: By induction on the structure of $C$[ ] (as the book hints at)

case: $C$[ ] is a variable, say $x$

then, for $F = \lambda y.x$, $F(\lambda \vec{x}.M) = x = C$[$M$]

case: $C$[ ] is [ ]

then, for $F = \lambda y.$[ ], $F(\lambda \vec{x}.M) = $ [ ] $ = C$[$M$]

case: $C$[ ] is $C_1$[ ]$C_2$[ ]

then, for $F = \lambda y.(C_1$[$y\vec{x}$]$C_2$[$y\vec{x}$]$), F(\lambda \vec{x}.M) = C$[$M$] (by induction)

case: $C$[ ] is $\lambda y.C_1$[ ]

then, for $F = \lambda z.(\lambda y.C_1$[$z\vec{x}$]$)$, $F(\lambda \vec{x}.M) = C$[$M$] (by induction)

---

I am happy to provide any further definitions if required

Comment: Is $F$ supposed to be a term or a context? I guess it should be a term. If so, your answer is incorrect, in the case when $C[ ]$ is the hole.

Comment: Yes, $F$ is supposed to be a term. I do think that $F = \lambda y.$[ ] is meaningless, but can't find a way to get around this.

Comment: OK. I think I figured it out, the result of substituting $M$ in [ ] is not [ ]! For the case where $C$[ ] $=$ [ ], $F = \lambda y.y\vec{x}$ works. I *think* the other cases are correct

Comment: Exactly! Well done!